# Why are elves immune to a ghoul's paralyzing touch?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, immunities, elf

I was reading [Are Half-Elves immune to the paralyzing property of a Ghoul's Claw action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59518/10867) and it struck me that I have no idea as to why elves would be immune to the paralyzing touch of a ghoul, but it has nonetheless been part of D&D lore since *[Monsters & Treasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_%281974%29)*. Is this based off of Tolkien? Traditional lore? Gygax and Arneson's shared world?

Comment: Just to check, you're interested in the original reason? Some editions have explanations specific to that edition.

Comment: @Miniman: I hadn't realized that the reasoning had changed. I had assumed there was a reason from the start that had stayed constant.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Sorry, I meant in-universe explanations.

Comment: I’ve removed the [history-of-gaming] tag since this is just a lore question and doesn’t anything to do with the history of the hobby or franchise.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've seen three (4, now that I've seen harlandski's Gygax quote) reasons for Elves being immune to a Ghoul's paralysis ability:

## Positive Energy

Per the [Gygax quote](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?215360-When-did-ghouls-become-undead/page2&p=3967138#post3967138), elves are suffused with positive energy, rendering them immune to the negative energy which powers a Ghoul's paralysis.

## Tolkien Immortality (and historical inertia)

Apparently, an old source book (PC1: Tall Tales of the Wee Folk Pg 24) states that Ghouls' paralysis is caused by the victim's fear of death; Elves (who are immortal, in the Tolkien Immortality "can't die of old age" sense) thus have a sufficiently different vision of death that they're immune. ([source](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l012?Bestiary-A-ghast-s-paralysis-even-affects-elves#5))

## Historical Inertia

Chainmail, on which D&D was (in large part) based, made Elves immune to Ghoul paralysis as a balance mechanic: Ghouls were cheap, Elves were expensive, and the immunity prevented Ghouls from zerg-rushing Elves. ([source](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pc2o?Elven-Immunities-trait-and-ghouls-paralysis#12))

## Pathfinder Lore

In Golarion (the default Pathfinder setting), the first Ghoul was an Elf, and the elven immunity to their paralysis is a manifestation of that.

> The fact that elves have an unusual immunity to this paralysis is curious indeed, but most point to Kabriri’s form (and to the almost elven features of most ghouls) as the answer. They say that before he succumbed to his cannibal urge and became a demon, Kabriri himself was an elf. The long ears and slender bodies that most ghouls develop, despite their original race, is thus an echo of Kabriri’s legacy—and the fact that their paralytic hungers have no effect on elves is but another manifestation of this strange bit of history.

([source](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l012?Bestiary-A-ghast-s-paralysis-even-affects-elves#15))

---

**Significant Limitation/Caveat**: all of these sources are second- or third-hand, and some are definitely retroactive and/or campaign-world-specific explanations.

Comment: @harlandski If true, the chainmail reference is the best answer to this question, imo.  What's your source for "no exception made for elves"?  I'm finding more sources saying there was an exception, such as this: http://quicklyquietlycarefully.blogspot.com/2012/08/ghouls-in-od-and-chainmail.html

Comment: @Brilland The OD&D extract in there says: _"As stated in CHAINMAIL for Wights, Ghouls paralize any normal figure they touch, excluding Elves."_ Sounds like it's saying that Elves had immunity to ***Wights*** in Chainmail (not necessarily Ghouls), and OD&D might have adopted that for Ghouls on its own. Unless OD&D Ghouls and Chainmail Wights are the same thing?

Comment: @Brilliand I have a copy of Chainmail 3rd Edition in front of me. I can't fit the whole entry for Wights (and Ghouls) into comments, but elves are not excluded. "If they touch a normal figure during melee, it becomes paralyzed and remains so for one complete turn. A paralyzed figure is considered to be able to strike a blow at the Wight just prior to paralysis taking effect, so melee can occur but only one round." Doppelgreener is right that Wights and Ghouls are conflated, and even Zombies are tacked on the end. But no immunity for elves to paralysis on Chainmail p29.

Comment: minnmass, I've edited the full Chainmail citations into my answer. See what you want to do with your Chainmail citation now. I could be wrong in my inclusion of elves as "fantasy figures", and it could be that elves were added to the immune category during play, but the Chainmail RAW give no such particular immunity for elves.

Comment: @harlandski I don't think elves are considered "normal unit" (and in this case normal = mortal, since normal units are all chainmail units that are NOT in the fantasy supplement ... and elves are magical in terms of being able to turn invisible ...) but you'd have to think through that based on unit costs to arrive at that decision. Chainmail 3e, this might be one of those issues that was decided but a 4th edition was not released, I'll check out Strat Review articles ... don't recall seeing anything on that before.

Comment: @harlandski (Page 29) "Those Elves (and Fairies) armed with magical weapons add an extra die in normal combat, and against *other fantastic creatures* they will perform even better" Fantastic versus normal is I think where that comes from.  The nitpicky rule thing is ghouls influence "normal" units but not 'fantastic' units. Compare point value of elves - 4-  with Light foot _1_ heavy foot -2- and medium horse -4- ... they are definitely not a normal foot unit on that basis either. Page 27).

Comment: Actually, ghouls were not cheap.  Their unit cost was 10 points (p. 37, wights and ghouls) while the elves cost was 4 points (p. 29). Chainmail pages

Comment: What I'm saying is, that person over at your Paizo "source" is mistaken, and may never have read the Chainmail rules.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm impressed with your reasoning. I'll amend my answer to highlight the probable "fantasy/fantastic" nature of elves.

Answer (score 50):

### Gary Gygax (2007): Elves' *positive energy* makes them immune to paralysis from ghouls

Gary Gygax answered exactly this question [on a forum in 2007](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?215360-When-did-ghouls-become-undead/page2&p=3967138#post3967138), (typo original):

> When I devised the ghoul for the D&D game it was most assuredly with non-living energization, that is undead status, that enabled these creatures to exist and hunger for the flesh of dead humans and their ilk.
>
> (...)
>
> The negative energy of the ghoul is the rason for its paralyzing ability. **Elves, having great positive energy, are thus immune to the effect.**

What we are to make of such a late reminiscence is another question, but this is at least "from the horse's mouth".

### As Gygax said, this was *for the D&D game*. Chainmail has different ghouls

Contrary to [popular internet belief](http://quicklyquietlycarefully.blogspot.com/2012/08/ghouls-in-od-and-chainmail.html), elven immunity to a ghoul's touch is not derived from Chainmail. In Chainmail Ghouls are considered to be in the same 'class' as Wights, along with Zombies.

> WIGHTS (and Ghouls): Although they are foot figures, Wights (and Ghouls) melee as Light Horse and defend as Heavy Horse. They cannot be harmed by normal missile fire. Wights (and Ghouls) can see in darkness, and must subtract 1 from any die roll they roll when in full light. **If they touch a normal figure during melee, it becomes paralyzed and remains so for one complete turn**. A paralyzed figure is considered to be able to strike a blow at the Wight just prior to paralysis taking effect, so melee can occur but only one round. Zombies are in this class but attack as Orcs and move as Goblins. (Chainmail 3rd Edition, p. 37)

The meaning of 'a normal figure' is somewhat obscure. And elves could go either way:

- Elves are 'normal figures' as they are 'normal size', and so not immune
- Elves are 'fantasy figures', and so immune. (The citation below suggests that they are *fantastic creatures* which may well have been the same as *fantasy figures*.)

But in any case, there is no **specific** immunity for Elves in Chainmail.

### And different Elves...

Quoting the whole entry for Elves:

> ELVES (and Fairies): Armed with deadly bows and magical swords, Elves (and Fairies) are dangerous opponents considering their size and build. They can per form split-move and fire, even though they are footmen. When invisible Elves (and Fairies) cannot attack — or be attacked unless located by an enemy with the special ability to detect hidden or invisible troops — but they can become visible and attack during the same turn. Those Elves (and Fairies) armed with magical weapons add an extra die in normal combat, and against **other fantastic creatures** they will perform even better. [There follows a combat table] (Chainmail 3rd Edition, p. 29)

Note that Elves and Fairies are also conflated into one 'class'. In any case, though they have several special abilities, immunity to paralysis is not one of them.

Comment: It's possible that there may be a better answer later, but this is the best one so far.

Comment: The first part of this answer makes me thinks ghouls would seek out and try to feed on elves, as they are big, meaty piles of energy

Answer (score 14):

*Rules Compendium* for D&D 3.5e includes a sidebar by David Noonan, Birth of a Rule, on page 13. In the discussion, it includes this bit:

> Ever wonder why elves are immune to paralysis? As far as we can figure out, that immunity came from a game-balance issue in the original *Chainmail* rules, which mostly covered medieval warfare (with a fantasy supplement that spawned the game we all play today). Masses of low-cost undead troops were beating up high-cost elf troops, so the “elves are immune to paralysis” emerged as a balancing factor. More than thirty years later, we’re still using that rule.

Comment: I suspect that was a ruling after some play after the rules were published, but a 4th edition was never issued to address that imbalance/exploit.  Trying to find a reference ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yeah, the “emerged as a balancing factor” thing seems to suggest that this wasn’t published, just became a popular/recommended houserule (at least in certain areas). And even Mr. Noonan states that this is all only “as far as we can figure out.”

Comment: My search through what I have is exhausted, I can't find what I was hoping to find.  Sorry.  I was hoping to be of assistance but came up dry.  Tough question.

Answer (score 3):

From 5E Forgotten Realms WIKI:
Instead of serving Yeenoghu, Doresain instead turned to the Seldarine. They took pity on the demigod, who was then able to escape the Gnoll Lord's tyranny in return for granting elves immunity to the paralytic touch of his minions.[6]

Doresain was according to this was the first ghoul and favored by Orcus until losing his White Kingdom on the 423[?] layer of the abyss to the above mentioned Yeenoghu

Comment: Nice find! You can source that even better, though:) The wiki shows it’s from the Monster Manual’s Gnoll entry on page 148. You can quote directly from there!